# Problema em migração de PSR-0 para PSR-4

Tags: php, composer, php-autoload

sou novo por aqui mas ja programo há mais de 10 anos em PHP e estou programando Orientado a Objetos a pouco tempo. Fazendo uns testes vi que a PSR-0 está deprecated e então um projeto meu que estou desenvolvendo resolvi migrar para a PSR-4 ai começou o problema. na hora de rodar a aplicação começou a dar o seguinte erro:
Fatal error: Class 'PS\Init\Bootstrap' not found in E:\Projetos\Sistema\App\Init.php on line 6, sendo que o arquivo existe e funcionava na PSR-0.

vou postar o meu composer.json e a minha estrutura de pastas para ver se consigo arrumar esse erro senão vou ter que voltar para a PSR-0.

```
-/Sistema
   - App
      - Clientes
         - Controllers
         - Models
         - Views
      - Init.php
   - public
      - .htaccess
      - index.php
   - vendor
      - PS
         - Init
            - Bootstrap.php
```

composer.json

```
{
"name": "PortalSinos/Sistema",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3"
},

"minimum-stability": "alpha",
"authors": [
{
    "name": "Alexandro Zaleski",
    "email": "alexandro@portalsinos.com.br"
}
],
"autoload": {
"psr-4": {
    "PS\\": "vendor/",
    "App\\": "App/"
}
},
"config":{
    "bin-dir": "bin"
}}
```

Se puderem me ajudar a descobrir qual o erro, agradeço..

Valeu..

Comment: Uma sugestão: A questão dos namespaces, dê uma olhada, quem sabe algum ajuste resolva seu problema.

Comment: Olhei e re-olhei mas não consegui arrumar.. vou aguardar até amanhã.. caso não consiga, volto pra PSR-0 e toco o barco.. qualquer coisa mudo depois.. obrigado

Comment: Resolvido o problema.. aonde eu estava setando "PS\\": "vendor/" tive que colocar "PS\\": "vendor/PS/" ai funcionou.. Valeu